# Thread safe passing of data from service to activity - Android

Tags: java, android, singleton, android-service, asmack

I am working on developing and XMPP chat application and am using aSmack. I have a service that holds the XMPP connection, registers the roster and packet listeners etc.

Currently, my service logs in then calls connection.getRoster() and stores/updates all of the RosterEntrys (and their statuses) in a Singleton class. Then in the main activity I get all of these RosterEntrys back by calling Singleton.getInstance().getRosterEntrys() and populates a listView.

To no surprise, I am getting all sorts of race conditions and this isn't very thread safe. I'm thinking of ditching the Singleton idea altogether but I am not sure the best way to do so.

What would be the best way to transfer a Set from a service to an Activity in a Thread Safe way? I saw mentions of using a Singleton with a SynchronizedSet. Is this something worth looking into? Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solved this problem by registering a BroadcastListener on both the Service and the Activity. I then pass the ArrayList back and forth between the intents. This has shown to be a very clean and effective way to transfer a Collection of information between activities or services

Answer (score 0):

From the Service to UI, I would use the runOnUI method.

"Best" is subjective, for a reason somebody will say method1, fr other reason method2.

You can develop a synchronized method.

I am using AsyncTask-s to get messages from networking to UI, you can do various stuff at `onPostExecute` which is running on UI thread, like calling a synchronized method.

I hope it helps!

Comment: I have used bot AsyncTask-s and the runOnUI method and they are very useful for executing tasks in the background of the same activity then reflecting a change in the UI afterwards but I haven't tried using between files. I will explore this option and see if/how it is possible.

Comment: "What would be the best way to transfer a Set from a service to an Activity in a Thread Safe way?" that refers for transfer data from background task to ui.

Comment: Thank you  matheszabi. The runOnUI method is great if it is in the same file or in the most primitive examples where you only have one activity in your application however in multiple activity applications this isn't useful because you have no knowledge about what UI view is currently in the foreground.  I have solved this problem using broadcast listeners and passing ArrayList<Parcelable> back and forth between the intents. This has shown to be a very clean and effective way to transfer a Collection of information between activities or services